# SQLAlchemy ondelete and onupdate do not update the database

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy with a MySQL database using the InnoDB engine which does support ondelete and onupdate.

I have the following in my 'Posts' table which refers to an `Accounts` table:

```
account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

I updated the database using Flask-Migrate (Alembic) and I've noticed that the onupdate and ondelete values are not changed when I specify `onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"` even though it states I should use it like this in the [SQLAlchemy Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.params.ondelete)

What could be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `ondelete` and `onupdate` values don't update is because they cannot be changed when there is already that foreign key present.

To change it, I had to remove the foreign key from the table, update the database and then re-add it to the table with the values you want then update once again.